# How to focus on an alternate label using cocoa?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm still a noob to iPhone development so sorry for the dumb question. I'm creating an app that has a custom numeric keyboard. I have an IBAction 'buttonDigitPressed' that when a digit is pressed it will simply add the digit to a UILabel. Now I have another label that I wish to do the same yet I'm not sure how to gain 'focus' of that particular label. I placed an invisible button over the second label so when pressed hopefully I can call an action to switch the keyboard from the first label to the second label. Yet I have no clue how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having to put an invisible button over the UILabel is skanky. If you want the user to be able to tap a number to mean "next time I hit a digit, append its value to this number", you'll probably be happier if you just use a UIButton right from the start. You can make a UIButton that looks pretty much like a UILabel (i.e. it has no border or background color). To set a UIButton's title in code, call setTitle:forState: with the UIControlStateNormal state. So now you've got tappable numbers, i.e. these UIButtons.

Okay, so now let's pretend you've got, say, three UIButtons. You need to use an *instance variable* here. So, each button will have an action - let's say doButton:(id)sender. So doButton will store the value of sender (the button that was just pressed) in the instance variable. Now your buttonDigitPressed action just looks in that instance variable to learn which button to append to. That's part of the power of instance variables - they give a method in a class a place to store a value where another method in the same class can get at it.

Comment: But (commenting on my own answer) I would also like to point out that instead of a UILabel or a UIButton you could just use UITextFields. That's what they are for, after all! The user taps in one and the keyboard just appears, automatically, and now the user is editing *that* text field. Plus, you are allowed to specify a custom keyboard. Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'd love to use UITextFields yet I can't find anyway of completely disabling the keyboard as I am using a custom keyboard. I try the 'resignFirstResponder' but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Assign your custom keyboard view to the UITextField as its inputView.